# Express.js - On second POST request: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I send a POST request to my server on any route. It stores the data correctly in the database and returns a response with NO errors.

However, if I send another POST request to the same route, with correct & different POST information, it will work, data will be stored in the database & the return will be correct, but it will trigger an exception:

```
EntityAlreadyExistsException, mongoose _id: 5ad5e661f2b3935b5b485890 already exists
```

And then a:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
```

It seems like even though the response has been sent back to the client successfully on the first POST request, the data still remains in the API somehow.

Here is the response code:

```
public static Respond(res: any, errorKey: string, data: any) {
     if (errorKey && errorKey.length != 0) {
         let error = new Error(errorKey);
         res.status(error.HTTPCode).json(error.ToObject());
     } else {
         res.status(200).json({ data: data });
     }
 }
```

If the POST request is sent a third time the error is as follows:

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
EntityAlreadyExistsException mongoose _id: 5ad5e661f2b3935b5b485890 already exists
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
EntityAlreadyExistsException mongoose _id: 5ad5e661f2b3935b5b485890 already exists
Success
```

On sending a third POST request, the above will be repeated three times.
Strange thing is that the application works fine (stores the data correctly & sends the correct response back) except for these messages in the console.
The POST requests are sent via Postman.

There is a similar question here: [Can't set headers after they are sent. on second call to REST API using Node and express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734107/cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent-on-second-call-to-rest-api-using-node-and)

However that solution does not work in this case.

Routes file:

```
      public static Start(app: any, config: any) {

      /* Open Routes */

    UserRoutes.StartOpenRoutes(Routes.router, config);

      /* End Of Open Routes */

    Routes.router.use((req, res, next) => { Authenticator.Verify(req, res, next, config); });

      /* Closed Routes */
    app.use("/", Routes.router);

    ContainerRoutes.StartClosedRoutes(Routes.router, config);

    PredictionRoutes.StartClosedRoutes(Routes.router, config);

    TradeRoutes.StartClosedRoutes(Routes.router, config);

    UserRoutes.StartClosedRoutes(Routes.router, config);

    app.use((req: any, res: any) => {
        Response.Respond(res, "undefined_route", null);
    });
  }
```

Here are the trade routes (TradeRoutes):

```
public static StartClosedRoutes(router: express.Router, config: any) {
    router.post('/trades', (req, res, next) => { Validator.Validate(req, res, next, 'POST /trades'); }
    , (req, res, next) => { Authorizer.CheckPermission(req, res, next, Actions.ADD_TRADE); }
    , (req, res, next) => { TradeModule.Post(req, res, next, config); });

    router.put('/trades/:id', (req, res, next) => { Validator.Validate(req, res, next, 'PUT /trades'); }
        , (req, res, next) => { Authorizer.CheckPermission(req, res, next, Actions.UPDATE_TRADE); }
        , (req, res, next) => { TradeModule.Put(req, res, next, config); });

    router.get('/trades/:id', (req, res, next) => { Authorizer.CheckPermission(req, res, next, Actions.GET_TRADE); }
        , (req, res, next) => { TradeModule.Get(req, res, next, config); });

    router.get('/trades', (req, res, next) => { Authorizer.CheckPermission(req, res, next, Actions.GET_TRADE); }, (req, res, next) => { TradeModule.Index(req, res, next, config); });

    router.delete('/trades/:id', (req, res, next) => { Authorizer.CheckPermission(req, res, next, Actions.DELETE_TRADE); }
        , (req, res, next) => { TradeModule.Delete(req, res, next, config); });
}
```

Comment: Might help to see some more code. How are you handling the http requests? Can we see your routes?

Comment: No worries, just added them

Comment: I'm not sure what framework you are using but my guess would be that you are passing multiple handlers to handle each request. For your `/trades` route, are all the handlers getting called and trying to return a response? i.e. `Validator.Validate`, `Authorizer.CheckPermission` and `TradeModule.Post`?

Comment: The handlers in this case only return a response if there is an error, otherwise they call next() if that is what you're meaning, but I think I see where you are coming from

Comment: Well you are getting an error so as you say `next` should get called, but you are also calling `res.status(error.HTTPCode).json(error.ToObject());` which is trying to return a response. Try removing the `res.status...` and let the error handler handle the response then.

Comment: Although doing that didn't solve the problem it has demonstrated to me that if it's my second call to the POST request, the whole process will be called twice, if it's the 5th call, the whole process gets called 5 times. 
I will try my best to track down the bug, thanks alot for the help

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This problem was caused by not clearing the mongoose collectionChange boolean.

Whenever a collection in the mongo database was updated/deleted, an internal property for the collection called tradeChange would be set to true, so when the internal method SubmitChanges is called, it would check if any of the collections need CRUD operations.

Without resetting the value, the mongoose value propogated to the next call and so on.